# polars: is there any better way to merge couple of columns of dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

Polars, trying to merge couple of columns of sample dataframe with a timedelta. Is there a better way to do? This doesn't look clean:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import random
import string

start_time = date(2023, 1, 1)
num_rows = 30
check_date = date(2023, 1, 15)

timestamps = [start_time + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(num_rows)]
values = [random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(num_rows)]
random_numbers = [random.randint(0, 20) for _ in range(num_rows)]
names = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=5)) for _ in range(num_rows)]
df = pl.DataFrame({'timestamp': timestamps, 'value': values, 'delta': random_numbers, 'random_name': names})
df = df.with_columns((pl.col('timestamp') - pl.duration(days='delta')).alias('booked_date'))

booked = pl.all(pl.col('value') == 1, pl.col('booked_date') < check_date)
df_old = df.with_columns(pl.when(booked).then(1).alias('value_old'))
df = df[['timestamp', 'value', 'random_name']]

df_old = df_old.with_columns((pl.col('timestamp') - pl.duration(days=pl.lit(15))).alias('timestamp_old'))
df_old = df_old[['timestamp_old', 'value_old']]

df = df.join(df_old, left_on="timestamp", right_on="timestamp_old")                     
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('value_old').fill_null(0).alias('value_old'))
```